# REACT: Bind function to run only on click

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Could someone please explain to me why when i am trying to bind onClick action to element it works good until i dont add brackets to pass arguments to function?

```
getUser(id) {
    console.log(id);
}

renderResults(){
        if (typeof this.props.results[0] == 'undefined') {
            return null;
        } else {
            var results = this.props.results[0].payload;
            var formatedResults = results.map((singleResult) => {
                return (
                    <div className="col-md-4 single-result" key={singleResult.account_id} onClick={this.getUser(singleResult.id)}>
                        <div>{singleResult.nickname}</div>
                    </div>
                )
            });
            return formatedResults;
        }
    }
```

that code works on load instead of on click and returns x console logs just when page is loaded not when i click element, but when i remove brackets and i am console logging static text in getUser function it works good.

Any help or helpful links? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
onClick={(e) => this.getUser(singleResult.id)}
```

doc : https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html#passing-arguments-to-event-handlers

Comment: oh i see, thanks a lot it works

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're calling the function, instead of passing it to onclick.

You can bind the value to the function, with an arrow function, if you're not passing anything, then it will keep its state:

```
getUser = () => {
   console.log(this);
}

onClick={this.getUser}
```

or in your case pass the function to the onclick:

```
onClick={(e) => this.getUser(singleResult.id)}
```

You can read all about it [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html#passing-arguments-to-event-handlers)

Answer (score 1):

We have different ways to bind events to your DOM elements in react.

- One of the most commonly used way is using 'bind'
- Another is using arrow functions.
- Using public class fields syntax

In your scenario,  you are calling your function directly by doing `this.getUser(singleResult.id)`. This executes the method rather than binding it to your DOM element.

Try changing it to `this.getUser.bind(this, singleResult.id)` which should be passing your `singleResult.id` to your method.

Another way to do it is using arrow functions like `onClick={(e) => this.getUser(singleResult.id)}`

But be careful while using arrow functions because there are chances of unnecessary rendering of components in some scenarios.

Please make sure to take a look at the [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html) to give more details on events handing in react

Answer (score 1):

use constructor to bind the function. use inside your component. and all your codes as it is

```
constructor(props) {
            this.getUser = this.getUser.bind(this);
        }
```